# connecting to internet via PC (Ubuntu Linux) on mobile phone (sony ericsson)

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-9.10, mobile-phone

I have a Toshiba laptop with wi-fi connected internet.  Now I want to connect my phone to my laptop and use its Internet connection (I can't buy new wifi or 3g supported mobile phone). I have no problem connecting k610 to my laptop and even shared my GPRS internet connection with my PC. But can't do the contrary.

How can I connect my k610 mobile (which not support wi-fi connections) to the Internet via my Toshiba laptop (with Bluetooth)?

P.S: I'm using Ubuntu Linux 9.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Cellphones like that don't know how to *use* bluetooth PAN (private area network; ethernet encapsulation) or DUN (dial-up networking; point-to-point connections over AT modem emulation) services. They can only *provide* them (DUN in your case).

Comment: but I have an bluetooth internet option and setting in my cellphone ...  I just don't know how to use it

Comment: That option is not for *using* Internet connection, it is for providing it.